# Python type error | operator behaviour with str and int

Tags: python

`print("*" * 10)` this line in python print `*` 10 times.

However the when trying to `print("*" + 10)` there is a type error.

Why is there a difference in operator behaviour with `str` and `int`

Comment: because it has a sense to mulitply by int (duplicate string), but it has no sense to make addition. what is the question ?

Comment: what output do you expect with `"*" + 10` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `+` is a concatenator in Python, and you can concatenate two strings but not a string and an int. You can, of course, cast the int into a string and concatenate that with another string if that's what you want to do: `print("*" + (str(10)))`

The thing works with `*` because that operator will simply concatenate the string with itself as many times as indicated by the integer number, as you've observed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are well,

The asterisk (star)(*) operator is used in Python with more than one meaning attached to it.

```
a=10
b=20
a*b
```

returns 200, but For sequences such as string, list and tuple,  * is a repetition operator

```
m="Hello World."
m*3
```

it returns , 'Hello World.Hello World.Hello World'

Single asterisk as used in function declaration allows variable number of arguments passed from calling environment. Inside the function it behaves as a tuple.

```
def function(*arg):
    for i in arg:
        print (i)
```

It returns all the items in the args.

You can import all the functions of a library or python script with using single star(*)

```
from math import *
```

but for the "+" if you want to use between 2 variables with (int) and (str), it will give and error, because "+" can sum same types together.

I hope it answers your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a difference because it is a different operator, and operations of addition between `str` and `int` have not been implemented in Python.

Mostly because it is ambiguous. What would print("*" + 10) mean? Would it mean to concatenate the int as if it were a string as `"*10"`, or to add 10 to each character's ASCII value, or to evaluate the string as an int and then apply normal addition? Because of this ambiguity, it has been left unimplemented.